# How to I get CMake to see & use a single DLL that I need to link & run the simplest program?

Tags: dll, cmake, clion

I have a simple program, and a DLL `thirdparty.dll` I have to link against at compile- and run-time.  I put it in my CLion project's `lib/` directory.  No matter what I do, and after reading CMake and SO posts for hours, no, ***days***, I've tried many combinations, but I can't get CMake's `find_library` to actually find the library that is sitting **right there** in plain sight in the `lib/` directory.  I've used explicit paths, relative paths, full filenames, filenames without `.dll`, you name it, and no matter what, I always get the same useless message:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'OTHERDLL-NOTFOUND', needed by 'MyProgram.exe'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MyProgram.dir/all' failed
```

Here is the relevant current excerpt from `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_library(OTHERDLL NAMES thirdparty PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
add_library(OTHERDLL SHARED IMPORTED)

include_directories(include)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.c")

add_executable(MyProgram ${SOURCES} src/myprogram.c)
target_link_libraries(MyProgram OTHERDLL)
```

Comment: a) Put `message(STATUS "find_library returned ${OTHERDLL})` immediately after the call to `find_library`      b) Try `find_library(OTHERDLL NAMES thirdparty.dll PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)` (the complete library filename)    c) Revert b, and try renaming thirdparty.dll into libthirdparty.dll

Comment: Thanks @Antonio, I just tried all 3 things.  No joy.

Comment: The first is a debug message, can you share which output it generates in the original code, and after modification b and c?

Comment: Sure, as soon as I can get CLion to actually show the debug message.  Sometimes (rarely) it does, most of the time it doesn't at all.  Trying to figure that out too.

Comment: What about using `cmake` or `cmake-gui`? Especially the second, should be simple enough

Comment: CMake GUI doesn't know the value of CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.  It knows the other things it needs (location of C & Fortran compilers.)  Wondering how I specify CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM in CMake GUI.  Never mind, got it (+ Add Entry button).

Comment: message() finally did print:  find_library returned /cygdrive/c/Users/Me/Documents/C/CProjects/MyProgram/lib/thirdparty.dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this tutorial](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets), when combining `find_library` and `add_library` you should use the library name (and not the full path) in the `add_library` call, and then set the imported location. So:

```
find_library(OTHERDLL NAMES thirdparty PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
message(STATUS "find_library returned ${OTHERDLL}")
add_library(anyNameIsGood SHARED IMPORTED) #anyNameIsGood could be thirdparty for example
set_property(TARGET anyNameIsGood PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${OTHERDLL}")
#(...)
target_link_libraries(MyProgram anyNameIsGood)
```

Comment: I'm going to keep this as the accepted answer, because I did get a clean build.  But for the record, I reloaded the project, and once again CLion/CMake gave the same error again.  After it had worked before!  I don't know whether to hate CLion or CMake or both.

Comment: @gknauth What does the message print?

Comment: msg 1: Error:The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OTHERDLL
    linked by target "MyProgram" in directory /cygdrive/c/Users/Me/Documents/C/CProjects/MyProgram

Comment: msg 2: Warning:find_library returned OTHERDLL-NOTFOUND
 Called from: [1] /cygdrive/c/Users/Me/Documents/C/CProjects/MyProgram/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @gknauth What is the content of the directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Me/Documents/C/CProjects/MyProgram/lib`?

Comment: 8407435 05-09 05:24 thirdparty.dll
3539372 04-21 16:14 cygwin1.dll
 783156 05-09 05:23 libthirdparty.dll.a
 363908 05-09 05:24 libthirdparty_f90.dll.a

Comment: Actually, yes it is, I just edited in the comment the actual name (cygeccodes) to the name I used in the question (thirdparty).

Comment: are you sure the names match?

Comment: @gknauth Last try, just a guess: If it happens at the `second` configure, it could be because (as I in fact suggested) you use as target name in `add_library` (anyNameIsGood) the same name used in `find_libraries` (thirdparty).

Comment: This is what it looks like now:  find_library(OTHERDLL NAMES thirdparty PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
add_library(thirdparty SHARED IMPORTED)

Comment: I delete the entire build folder CLion had constructed, and reloaded again, and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

In CMake you should use ${...} to call a variable, so instead of

```
target_link_libraries(MyProgram OTHERDLL)
```

use

```
target_link_libraries(MyProgram ${OTHERDLL})
```

Comment: That was it, thanks @AlexseyPetrov (and @Antonio).  Now if only I could figure out how, in CLion w/CMake, to get the Run button to see that DLL at run-time as well...  But that's a separate question I already asked on SO.

Comment: In addition, you can add set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".lib" ".dll") before find_library to force searching *.lib and *.dll on windows

Comment: @gknauth This cannot possibly be the solution. When you had the error `No rule to make target 'OTHERDLL-NOTFOUND', needed by 'MyProgram.exe'. ` cmake was clearly replacing the variable `OTHERDLL` with its content `"OTHERDLL-NOTFOUND"`

Comment: Yes @Antonio, you're right.  Looks like what AlexeyPetrov did for me was fix another problem I had, but it did result in a clean build, even if I still can't run the executable (because the DLL can't be found at runtime).  Anyway, as I wrote above:  message() finally did print: find_library returned /cygdrive/c/Users/Me/Documents/C/CProjects/MyProgram/lib/thirdparty.dll